# jplaylist - use jquery-ui sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable, jplayer

I want the users to be able to edit their own playlists, so I want to use `jquery-ui.sortable` with it and allow them to sort the tracks.

When I apply the sortable `$('#jp_container_1 ul').sortable()` it allows me to sort the items, but it seems that logically the jplaylist doesn't undertand it. So that jplayer ends up playing the musics on the initial orders.

Does anybody knows how to make sortable works with jplaylist?

Comment: Can you provide minimal code to replicate the issue or a small demo like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the issue..?